# Unhandled Exception while trying to sort

Tags: c++, sorting, unhandled-exception, median

I keep getting an unhandled exception in this portion of code whenever it runs, I have looked through it and can't see a clear reason. It will run fine up to the system pause that is commented out so it has to be something past that.Or maybe it is how I am setting my pivot?

```
template <class elemType>
int arrayListType<elemType>::medianpartition(int p, int r)
{
    int middle = list[(r+p)/2];
    int pivot = 0;

    if(list[p]<list[r]){
        if(middle<list[r]){
            if(list[p]<middle){
                pivot = middle;
            }else if(list[p]>middle){
                pivot = list[p];
            }
        }else if(middle>list[r]){
            pivot = list[r];
        }
    }else if(list[p]>list[r]){
        if(middle<list[r]){
            pivot = list[r];
        }else if(middle>list[r]){
            if(middle<list[p]){
                pivot = middle;
            }else if(middle>list[p]){
                pivot = list[p];
            }
        }
    }

    //system("Pause>nul");

    while ( p < r )
    {
        while ( list[p] < pivot )
            p++;

        while ( list[r] > pivot )
            r--;

        if ( list[p] == list[r] )
            p++;
        else if ( p < r )
        {
            int tmp = list[p];
            list[p] = list[r];
            list[r] = tmp;
        }
    }

    return r;
}
```

This is the function that calls it:

```
template <class elemType>
void arrayListType<elemType>::medianquicksort(int p, int r)
{
    if ( p < r )
    {
        int j = medianpartition(p, r);        
        medianquicksort(p, j-1);
        medianquicksort(j+1, r);
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What happens if `list[p]` is never less than `pivot`?

Comment: It would just go to the next loop where it would decrement r?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `list[p] == list[r]` then `pivot` is not assigned any value from the array and stays with its default value of zero. And if all items of the array are greater than zero, or all are less than zero, then one of the `while` loops runs `p` or `r` out of array's bounds.

Comment: there are no duplicate values in the array

Comment: Then why are you testing `if( list[p] == list[r] ) p++; else ...`?

Comment: Oh I see what you are saying, so I should test for p=r in the part where I set the pivot.

Comment: 'there are no duplicate values in the array' does NOT guarantee that `middle == list[r]` won't happen. And you test only fot *less-than* and *greater than* leaving the *equal* case unhandled...

Comment: ok so i tried to add in an if(p!=r)to check the pivot statements but i still get the error. Should I set the pivot to p or r when p and r equal?

Comment: No, you should just remove superfluous `if`-s. Simply do `if( < ) {} else {}` so that the median selection handles *equal* case under all `else` clauses.

Answer (score 0):

Think about this: what happens if every element in your array is the same value?

You have too many if else if statements when trying to figure out the pivot, and you didn't account for the possibility that list[p], list[r] and/or middle have the same value. I don't know if that's the root of your problem, but it's certainly a problem.

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified that in the rest of the program there is a part of my insert function that prevents duplicates. This is also an array

Comment: Ah ok, I figured but I was just saying that's an issue that's easy to fix. Also, try using some try catch blocks.